# VR/360 playback of gameplay recording

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, game-development, unreal-engine4, virtual-reality

Apologies if this question has been asked before, and apologies too if it is obvious to those with knowledge - I'm completely tech illiterate especially when it comes to gaming etc so bear with me!

I'm wondering whether it is possible to record gameplay (any console/platform) but be able to play this back in a 360/VR format?

The usecase is this:
I want to watch and follow a game but rather than having 1st person PoV, I'd love to be able to use either a VR headset device (most ideal) or a 360 viewer (tablet or smartphone) to move perspective beyond forward facing field of vision.
Ideally the PoV would follow players (think specatator mode) and not necessarily be a static camera - although not necessarily a deal breaker.

Is this possible?
How would this be done with existing tools etc or would new tools need to be developed?
Would it be 'recorded' client side or serverside - and would this matter?

Huge thanks in advance - also very very happy to be pointed in the direction of sources of info around this subject to consume if readily available.
Thanks
S

Comment: Better try to ask on : [gamedev](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: An interesting question, try gamedev.com or forum.unity3d

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect the gameobject(character) in your game that has the camera to your VR display (wherever you are coding the display at) and write a code that takes the image that it displaces in that camera under that gameobject and make it so it is continuously updating, making it seem like you are in the game.

look here http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/VROverview.html